# How to show links in Google search results like this

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I am wondering how can I show my website links like this (with ">" sign) in google search results.

[image]

I have also noticed that when I click to these types of results, they take me to altogether on a different page of that website. Dont know if they are doing 301 redirect.Please do let me know if there is any SEO benefit by displaying links like this and doing redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer....It is done using schema.org. What actually google is showing in the search result is a breadcrumb. I have to tell google about my breadcrumb using rich snippet.

Comment: You are right. Those are rich snippets. The definition and usage examples can be found on http://schema.org

Answer (score 0):

It's a SEO trick. When you're going to submit a website to Google with webmasters account. You have something called sitemap. It's what Google uses to give those nice clean results. You can generate sitemap for you site [here](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)

Comment: I dont think sitemap has anything to do with this. I am also generating and submitting sitemap already.

Comment: @Nancy read this then SiteMaps(https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en)

Comment: I got the answer....It is donr using schema.org. What actually google is showing in the search result is a breadcrumb. I have to tell google ablout my breadcrumb using rich snippet.